# Куда нужно вставить ID подписки в Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Не совсем ясен механизм создания платной подписки в приложении. После создания id подписки его нужно вставлять в код или нет?

Answer (score 0):

Ну для запрос делаешь для него и ProductDetails  получаешь

```
private fun queryProductDetails() {
        val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()

        val productList: MutableList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> = arrayListOf()

        productList.add(
            QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                .setProductId("subs.oneyear") //можно опустить
                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                .build()
        )
 params.setProductList(productList).let { productDetailsParams ->
            billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(productDetailsParams.build(), this)
        }
}
```

Оно?